# XSLT for chat logs: displaying a node value only on the first instance of that value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm applying an XSLT stylesheet to an XML chat log and want to only display the chatter's name the first time it appears in consecutive groups of messages, so that multiple lines  are "grouped" by chatter in each message group. An example illustrates this better.

I want to go from this:

```
<Cthon98> hey, if you type in your pw, it will show as stars
<Cthon98> ********* see!
<AzureDiamond> hunter2
<AzureDiamond> doesnt look like stars to me
```

To this:

```
<Cthon98> hey, if you type in your pw, it will show as stars
          ********* see!
<AzureDiamond> hunter2
               doesnt look like stars to me
```

My XSL (which is iterated once per chat line) is this:

```
<xsl:template match="User">
    <!-- add a comma before all but the first user -->
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>

    <!-- Pseudocode:
        1. Set variable to name of current chatter
        2. Set variable to name of previous line's chatter
        3. If current chatter == previous chatter, don't display name
        4. If current chatter != previous chatter, display name
    -->

    <!-- This displays the name -->
    <xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyName"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Can someone help me convert that pseudocode? Thanks so much!

Edit: the input XML is essentially a repetition of the following to/from message structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='MessageLog.xsl'?>
<Log FirstSessionID="1" LastSessionID="20">
    <Message>
        <From><User FriendlyName="chatter1"/></From>
        <To><User FriendlyName="chatter2"/></To>
        <Text>hey</Text>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <From><User FriendlyName="chatter2"/></From>
        <To><User FriendlyName="chatter1"/></To>
        <Text>hey!</Text>
    </Message>
</Log>
```

Comment: @BigJeffrey - You need to show us an example of your input XML

Comment: @lwburk - Is this definitely necessary? I thought all I'd need was the chatter's name and then it'd just be a case of using a "$beenHereOnceAlready" flag variable or something?

Comment: @BigJeffrey - There are a couple of ways to do grouping in XSLT. I could provide some generic information, but it's generally more satisfying for everyone if a complete solution can be provided. And that requires example input.

Comment: @BigJeffrey - Also, one thing's not clear: do you want to group all messages by a given user or just consecutive messages by the same user?

Comment: @lwburk - Done. :) I've edited my post. Also I want to group consecutive messages by the same user - not all of them. I'm sure it just requires some kind of flag which is checked/set once per iteration. The XSL iterates once per each chat line (regardless of which user's line it is).

Comment: @BigJeffrey - You don't need a flag. Just check explicitly whether the preceding `<Message>` is from the same user each time and suppress the name if it is. See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent the name from showing for consecutive messages from the same user is to check the `preceding-sibling` axis. The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Message">
        <xsl:if
            test="not(From/User/@FriendlyName = preceding-sibling::Message[1]/From/User/@FriendlyName)">
            <xsl:value-of select="From/User/@FriendlyName" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="Text" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following input:

```
<Log FirstSessionID="1" LastSessionID="49">
    <Message>
        <From><User FriendlyName="chatter1"/></From>
        <To><User FriendlyName="chatter2"/></To>
        <Text>hey</Text>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <From><User FriendlyName="chatter1"/></From>
        <To><User FriendlyName="chatter2"/></To>
        <Text>message two</Text>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <From><User FriendlyName="chatter2"/></From>
        <To><User FriendlyName="chatter1"/></To>
        <Text>hey you!</Text>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <From><User FriendlyName="chatter1"/></From>
        <To><User FriendlyName="chatter2"/></To>
        <Text>hey</Text>
    </Message>
</Log>
```

Produces the following output:

```
chatter1
hey
message two
chatter2
hey you!
chatter1
hey
```

**Edit:** I would probably handle each case in its own template, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template
        match="Message[not(From/User/@FriendlyName = preceding-sibling::Message[1]/From/User/@FriendlyName)]">
        <!-- name and text -->
        <xsl:value-of select="From/User/@FriendlyName" />
        <xsl:value-of select="Text" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Message">
        <!-- text only -->
        <xsl:value-of select="Text" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for this - some nice techniques here. But it seems to return true each time. If I add some text to my template inside the `if`, e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="From/User/@FriendlyName" />SOME_TEXT`, that text appears on every chat line. Also the chatter's name is not produced. Sorry I can't post the full XML and XSL - it's pretty huge. If it helps, these are MSN chat logs I'm manipulating.

Comment: @BigJeffrey - That must be due to some difference in the input XML that you're not showing. See my edit for a way to handle each case in its own template.

Comment: Excellent, thanks, the preceding-sibling was what I was looking for, I think! Didn't know about that selector, so thank you very much! :)

Comment: Three things with this approach: you need to address the **immediate** sibling otherwise it won't work with multiple responses; `current()` it's not allow in XSLT 1.0 patterns; using node set comparison makes `current()` not needed. Pattern for first case: `Message[From/User/@FriendlyName = preceding-sibling::Message[1]/From/User/@FriendlyName]`

Comment: @Alejandro - Right you are. Fixed.